# Create a status bar in Xcode / Xamarin

Tags: c#, xcode, cocoa, xamarin, monomac

I am building an OS X application in C# and MonoMac using Xamarin Studio and Xcode Interface Builder.

I want to create a status bar (no, not an icon inside the global menu) in my application. One that looks like the one in Finder which you can see if you click View -> Show Status Bar.

I figured I start by placing a custom view at the bottom of my main window and then place some labels and buttons etc inside it.

But I want the background of the custom view to be "textured" (the grey gradient).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[_window setContentBorderThickness:24.0 forEdge:NSMinYEdge];

This is the objective-c call on your window that will give you the look of the bottom bar in Finder. The equivalent in C# would be:

```
Window.SetContentBorderThickness (24, NSRectEdge.MinYEdge);
```